# how to send variable of type Func<T,decimal> to sum from IQueryable using ef core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to send a lamda in function parameter
but when i do that i've error say

> Expression of type 'System.Func`2[KokazGoodsTransfer.Models.Receipt,System.Decimal]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[KokazGoodsTransfer.Models.Receipt,System.Decimal]]' of method 'System.Decimal Sum[Receipt](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[KokazGoodsTransfer.Models.Receipt], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[KokazGoodsTransfer.Models.Receipt,System.Decimal]])' (Parameter 'arg1')'

example of code

```
var sum = await context.Receipts.GroupBy(c => c.ClientId).Select(c => new { c.Key, Sum = c.Sum(c=>c.Amount) }).ToListAsync();
```

it's work fine

but when i try this  i see the error

```
Func<Receipt, Decimal> func = c => c.Amount;
var sum = await context.Receipts.GroupBy(c => c.ClientId).Select(c => new { c.Key, Sum = c.Sum(func) }).ToListAsync();
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF usually requires an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) to be able to translate the code into actual SQL query.

You can try something like this (though not tested, but in some cases such tricks worked as far as I remember):

```cs
Expression<Func<Receipt, Decimal>> func = c => c.Amount;
var sum = await context.Receipts
    .GroupBy(c => c.ClientId)
    .Select(c => new { c.Key, Sum = c.AsQueryable().Sum(func) })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Otherwise you maybe will need either to build select statement expression manually (which is not that easy) or look into 3rd party library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) which allows [to use `Func`'s](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#plugging-expressions-into-entitysets--entitycollections-the-solution) with some magic. Something along this lines:

```cs
Expression<Func<Receipt, Decimal>> func = c => c.Amount;
var sum = await context.Receipts
    .AsExpandable() // or WithExpressionExpanding on the context DI set up
    .GroupBy(c => c.ClientId)
    .Select(c => new { c.Key, Sum = c.Sum(func.Compile()) })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I know LinQkit and I used it , but let me test  your Solution and i will tell you thank you

Comment: @TariqHajeer I don't see any calls like `AsExpandable()` in your code. Or you have set it up on the DI level?

Comment: another somthing do you have a good course thant explane Expression as well  as you understand it ?

Comment: Guys, I have implemneted `WithExpressionExpanding` but you still put `AsExpandable()`

Comment: it's work but without use WithExpressionExpanding

Comment: and work wihtout  AsExpandable

Comment: @TariqHajeer was glad to help! As for the expressions trees - try the linked docs, it maybe not  perfect start but not bad either.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use not `Func` but `Expression<Func<Receipt, Decimal>>`. But it also will be not translatable without third-party extensions. I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It needs just configuring `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .WithExpressionExpanding();     // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then your query will work in the following way:

```cs
Expression<Func<Receipt, Decimal>> func = c => c.Amount;

var sum = await context.Receipts.GroupBy(c => c.ClientId)
  .Select(c => new { c.Key, Sum = c.Sum(x => func.Invoke(x)) })
  .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It's work wothout us WithExpressionExpanding