# Reusing where conditions in EF Core

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have this `IQueryable` in EF Core 6, and get stuck on trying to refactor this, because I want to have separate methods, which can calculate specials or travel pay when I pass there `IGrouping`, and it inserts it in `IQueryable` back. Is it possible, щr I want something that can't be.

This is the query:

```
var splitQuery = joinedWithFees.GroupBy(q => new
        {
            q.CarrierId,
            q.ProfitCenterId,
         })
        .Select(g => new CarrierReportDto
        {
            CarrierId = g.Key.CarrierId,
            Standard = g.Where(x => x.IsInSplit)
                .Sum(x => x.SettlementAmount),
            Specials = g.Where(x => x.IsInSplit)
                .Where(x => isNotInvoiced && !x.SettlementId.HasValue || !isNotInvoiced)
                .Where(x => !startDate.HasValue || x.FeeDate >= startDate && !endDate.HasValue || x.FeeDate <= endDate)
                .Where(x => x.GroupId == (int)FeeTypeGroups.Special)
                .Sum(x => x.SettlementAmount),
            TravelPay = g.Where(x => x.IsInSplit)
                .Where(x => isNotInvoiced && !x.SettlementId.HasValue || !isNotInvoiced)
                .Where(x => !startDate.HasValue || x.FeeDate >= startDate && !endDate.HasValue || x.FeeDate <= endDate)
                .Where(x => x.GroupId == (int)FeeTypeGroups.TravelTeam)
                .Sum(x => x.SettlementAmount)
       };,
```

I want to reuse some conditions in it, how I can do that?

For example this one:

```
x => isNotInvoiced && !x.SettlementId.HasValue || !isNotInvoiced
```

If I use an `Expression` like this:

```
Expression<Func<Model, bool>> pred = x => isNotInvoiced && !x.SettlementId.HasValue || !isNotInvoiced
```

it fails before compiling or on compiling, because EF can't do that.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: There are a lot of answers in SO, one with [LINQKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043135/10646316)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `AsQueryable` before filtering:

```cs
Expression<Func<Model, bool>> pred = x => isNotInvoiced && !x.SettlementId.HasValue || !isNotInvoiced

// ...

Specials = g.AsQueryable().Where(pred)
```

Have not tested against EF Core 6 but for EF Core 7 simple repro works.

Also you can try looking into using LINQKit like in [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73491555/2501279).